# Is there a difference between having no key and a static key prop (for a non list element)?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

For the background to this question, [see this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75757046/can-the-react-context-api-change-based-on-prop-change-without-using-useeffect-or).

Due to how loading and passing data to pages with `getServerSideProps` in React works, as described in the link above, I am looking for a way to immediately get rid of and reinitialise the React context on a page load. After some research, I have found that I might be able to use the `key` property for this. My idea is to add a key property on a `div` in the `_app.tsx` file, and make the value change when I need to reset the app's state.

Something like this (simplified example):

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div key="some-key">
      <!-- Rest of the app -->
    </div>
  );
}
```

The change would only happen when I need the context to change on render, instead of in a use effect. The scenario being that Next returns new data from the server, but it takes a render + a use effect before the context is updated, causing Next to first render with new values in its props, but old values in the state. Some data is read from props, and some from the context.

My question is if there is a difference between these two examples:

```
// Example 1 (same as above, with key)
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div key="some-key">
      <!-- Rest of the app -->
    </div>
  );
}

// Example 2 (no key)
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <!-- Rest of the app -->
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am asking because it is unclear to me if adding a key will impact the app in other ways, like how it re-renders or other (except when the key changes). I know React uses the key to identify an element, and I want to tell it: "Hey, this app has completely changed, reinitialise it", but I don't want to change any other behaviour. I want it to work exactly like before I added the `key` prop, and then be able to change the key prop to reinitialise the app.

Yes, I know it can be a performance issue, but I don't really see this happening often, if at all.

Comment: It's kinda hard to answer the question because it's hard to be certain that the key doesn't change absolutely anything without knowing React internals. However, it's fine to force re-render by changing the key like you are planning to do.

Comment: I guess my main concern is that the key staying the same would prevent some re-renders or something, as opposed to having no key. But as far as I have read, I don't think that should be the case.